# Lisview inside a Listview not working

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app that shows weather using OWM 5day 3hour forecast API, The ui consists of EditText to input a city name, a button to initiate the call process, a listview that will display 5 entries (five days) and each day entry includes another listview that displays decription and temperature for every 3 hours in a day,
I am able to see the listview for days but cannot see the nested listview for the hourly data. My classes include : MainActivity, WeatherAdapter to show 3hourly weather, DayAdapter to show day entries, and JsonToWeather data class that extracts data out of the Json response and make an Arraylist of data for only one particular day. I tried to log the error and highlighted the error position by a comment.
MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private String responseJSON = null;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherDataArrayList;
WeatherAdapter weatherAdapter = null;
EditText cityName;
String city = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dayList);
    cityName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
    Button load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            city = cityName.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: city is : " + city);
            if(city == null){
                Toast toast = null;
                toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter a city before continuing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } else {

                String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + (city.toLowerCase()) + "&units=metric&appid=8b10912e19fde267f36f6cb785ee7efd";

                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: staring download task");
                DownloadJSON downloadJSON = new DownloadJSON();
                downloadJSON.execute(url);
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: after downloadtask");
            }
        }
    });


    if(weatherDataArrayList == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ArrayList is Still null");
    }
}

private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadJSON";

    private String downloadJSON(String url){
        StringBuilder jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            URL apiURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) apiURL.openConnection();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadJSON: Response code "+ responseCode);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            int charReader;
            char[] inputBuffer = new char[500];
            while(true){
                charReader = reader.read(inputBuffer);
                if(charReader < 0){
                    break;
                }
                if(charReader > 0){
                    jsonResult.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charReader));
                }
            }
            reader.close();
            return jsonResult.toString();
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadJSON: URL is Invalid");
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadJSON: IO Error");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: url is : " + strings[0]);
        String jsonResponse = downloadJSON(strings[0]);
        if(jsonResponse == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: Error downloading");
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResponse) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonResponse);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: json received is : " + jsonResponse);
        if(jsonResponse != null){
            JsonToWeatherData jtwd = new JsonToWeatherData();
            weatherDataArrayList = jtwd.extractor(jsonResponse);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String date1 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            String date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            String date3 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            String date4 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            String date5 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
            days.add(date1);
            days.add(date2);
            days.add(date3);
            days.add(date4);
            days.add(date5);
            DayAdapter day = new DayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.layout_day_card,days,weatherDataArrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(day);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: no json recieved, city is Wrong");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please provide a valid city!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}
} 

WeatherAdapter : 
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WeatherData> {
private static final String TAG = "WeatherAdapter";
private final int layoutResourceID;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<WeatherData> block;

public WeatherAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<WeatherData> block) {
    super(context, resource, block);
    this.layoutResourceID = resource;
    this.block = block;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    Log.d(TAG, "WeatherAdapter: called constructor");
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceID,parent,false);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "getView: entered");
    WeatherData weatherData = block.get(position);
    TextView temp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    temp.setText(weatherData.getTemp());
    TextView shortDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descrip);
    shortDesc.setText(weatherData.getShortDesc());
    return convertView;
}
}

DayAdapter : 
public class DayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private static final String TAG = "DayAdapter";
private ArrayList<String> dayBlock;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private int layoutresourceID;
private ArrayList<WeatherData> dayWeather, fullBlock;
private Context context;
JsonToWeatherData json = new JsonToWeatherData();

public DayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<String> dayBlock, ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherBlock) {
    super(context, resource, dayBlock);
    this.context = context;
    this.dayBlock = dayBlock;
    this.fullBlock = weatherBlock;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.layoutresourceID = resource;
    if(fullBlock == null){
        Log.e(TAG, "DayAdapter: full block is null");
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutresourceID,parent,false);
    }
    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView minTempFoDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minTempOfDay);
    TextView maxTempFoDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.maxTempOfDay);
    ListView weatherHolderListView = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wHoldLV);
    String dateString = dayBlock.get(position);
    dayWeather = json.extractByDate(fullBlock,dateString);
    if(fullBlock == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: fullblock is null");
    }
    if(dayWeather == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: dayweather array is null");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: dayweather is not null");
    }
    String test = dayWeather.get(position).getTemp(); // error occured here
    Log.d(TAG, "getView: test string : " + test);
    date.setText(dateString);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    float mint = 500, maxt = 0;
    String mint1 = "", maxt1 = "";
    for(WeatherData data : dayWeather){
        if(mint > Float.parseFloat(data.getMinTemp())){
            mint = Float.parseFloat(data.getMinTemp());
            mint1 = df.format(mint);
            Log.d(TAG, "getView: mint : " + mint);
        }
        if (maxt > Float.parseFloat(data.getMaxTemp())){
            maxt = Float.parseFloat(data.getMaxTemp());
            maxt1 = df.format(maxt);
        }
    }
    minTempFoDay.setText(mint1);
    maxTempFoDay.setText(maxt1);
    WeatherAdapter weatherAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(context,R.layout.weather_holder,dayWeather);
    weatherHolderListView.setAdapter(weatherAdapter);

    return convertView;
}
}

JsonToWeatherData:
public class JsonToWeatherData {
private static final String TAG = "JsonToWeatherData";

public ArrayList<WeatherData> extractor(String jsonData){
    Log.d(TAG, "extractor: in the method");
    if(jsonData == null){
        return null; // if there is no json data is received
    } else {
        ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherDataArrayList = new ArrayList<WeatherData>();
        Log.d(TAG, "extractor: in the else field");
        try{
            Log.d(TAG, "extractor: in try block");
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            int count = root.getInt("cnt");
            JSONArray wList = root.getJSONArray("list");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
                WeatherData weather = new WeatherData();
                JSONObject wBlock = wList.getJSONObject(i);
                weather.setDate(wBlock.getString("dt_txt"));
                JSONObject mainObj = wBlock.getJSONObject("main");
                weather.setTemp(String.valueOf(mainObj.getDouble("temp")));
                weather.setMinTemp(String.valueOf(mainObj.getDouble("temp_min")));
                weather.setMaxTemp(String.valueOf(mainObj.getDouble("temp_max")));
                weather.setHumidity(String.valueOf(mainObj.getInt("humidity")));
                JSONArray warray = wBlock.getJSONArray("weather");
                JSONObject weatherObj = warray.getJSONObject(0);
                weather.setDescription(weatherObj.getString("description"));
                weather.setShortDesc(weatherObj.getString("main"));
                weather.setIconID(weatherObj.getString("icon"));
                weatherDataArrayList.add(weather);
                Log.d(TAG, "extractor: temp field is :" + weather.getTemp());
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weatherDataArrayList;
    }
}

public ArrayList<WeatherData> extractByDate(ArrayList<WeatherData> fullList,String date){
    ArrayList<WeatherData> dayweatherList = new ArrayList<WeatherData>();
    for( WeatherData weather : fullList ){
        if( ( weather.getDate().substring(0,9) ).equals(date) ){
            dayweatherList.add(weather);
        }
    }
    return dayweatherList;
}
}
```

What should I do?

Error message : (
        08-19 23:11:39.914 12148-12148/com.jugalmistry.apps.fivedaysofweather D/DayAdapter: getView: dayweather is not null
    08-19 23:11:39.916 12148-12148/com.jugalmistry.apps.fivedaysofweather D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    08-19 23:11:39.918 12148-12148/com.jugalmistry.apps.fivedaysofweather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.jugalmistry.apps.fivedaysofweather, PID: 12148
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
            at com.jugalmistry.apps.fivedaysofweather.DayAdapter.getView(DayAdapter.java:58)

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` pretty much sums up your problem. `DayAdapter.getView`, Do not just check for null on `dayWeather`, do a size check as well `if(dayWeather.size() > 0)...`

Comment: @Pierre It is evident that the size is zero but why is it zero. Have I done some wrong assignment or something? Why did the arrayList not get any data?

Comment: Override `getCount()` and return `dayWeather.getSize();`. `IndexOutofBounds` is not just necessarily `0`.

Comment: The problem I see in your code is that your `dayWeather`s size can differ for each position. Adapters like "steady" lists with a set size. When you alter the list  size, you also need to notify the adapter about the change every time. Rather "rethink" your data and how you want to display it. You need to set an array of data once, then just display it according to the position. Pre-build your list before setting it to the adapter.

Comment: Just add `if(position > dayWeather.getSize() - 1) { return convertView; }` before `dayWeather.get(position)` then your code should not break

Comment: Use expandable listview. Listview inside listview is really difficult to manage

Comment: we can be used expandable list view for nesting the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attempted to help you with the full code below.

I would also recommend you implement the ViewHolder pattern [ViewHolder pattern example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) for increased performance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    EditText cityName;
    String city = null;

    ListView dayListView;
    ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherDataArrayList;

    DayAdapter dayAdapter;
    //private String responseJSON = null;
    //WeatherAdapter weatherAdapter = null; // Creating this adapter within the DayAdapter

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cityName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        Button load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadButton);

        dayListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dayList);

        load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                city = cityName.getText().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: city is : " + city);
                if (city == null)
                {
                    Toast toast = null;
                    toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter a city before continuing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + (city.toLowerCase()) + "&units=metric&appid=8b10912e19fde267f36f6cb785ee7efd";

                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: staring download task");
                    DownloadJSON downloadJSON = new DownloadJSON();
                    downloadJSON.execute(url);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: after downloadtask");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void SetDayListData(ArrayList<String> dayBlock, ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherBlock)
    {
        if (dayAdapter == null)
        {
            dayAdapter = new DayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.layout_day_card, days, weatherDataArrayList);
            dayListView.setAdapter(dayAdapter);
        }
        else
        {
            //created a new method "UpdateData" just to update the data in the adapter
            dayAdapter.UpdateData(days, weatherDataArrayList);
            dayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        private static final String TAG = "DownloadJSON";

        private String downloadJSON(String url)
        {
            StringBuilder jsonResult = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                URL apiURL = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) apiURL.openConnection();
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadJSON: Response code "+ responseCode);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                int charReader;
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[500];
                while (true)
                {
                    charReader = reader.read(inputBuffer);
                    if (charReader < 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (charReader > 0)
                    {
                        jsonResult.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charReader));
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
                return jsonResult.toString();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadJSON: URL is Invalid");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "downloadJSON: IO Error");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: url is : " + strings[0]);
            String jsonResponse = downloadJSON(strings[0]);
            if (jsonResponse == null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: Error downloading");
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResponse)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonResponse);

            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: json received is : " + jsonResponse);
            if (jsonResponse != null)
            {
                JsonToWeatherData jtwd = new JsonToWeatherData();
                weatherDataArrayList = jtwd.extractor(jsonResponse);
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                String date1 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                String date2 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                String date3 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                String date4 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                String date5 = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
                days.add(date1);
                days.add(date2);
                days.add(date3);
                days.add(date4);
                days.add(date5);

                SetDayListData(days, weatherDataArrayList);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: no json recieved, city is Wrong");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please provide a valid city!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private static final String TAG = "DayAdapter";

    private Context context;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int layoutresourceID;

    private ArrayList<String> dayBlock;
    private ArrayList<WeatherData> dayWeather, weatherBlock;

    JsonToWeatherData json = new JsonToWeatherData();

    public DayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<String> dayBlock, ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherBlock)
    {
        super(context, resource, dayBlock);
        this.context = context;
        this.dayBlock = dayBlock;
        this.weatherBlock = weatherBlock;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.layoutresourceID = resource;

        if (weatherBlock == null)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "DayAdapter: full block is null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return dayBlock.getSize();
    }

    public void UpdateData(@NonNull ArrayList<String> dayBlock, ArrayList<WeatherData> weatherBlock)
    {
        this.dayBlock = dayBlock;
        this.weatherBlock = weatherBlock;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutresourceID,parent,false);
        }

        if (weatherBlock == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "getView: weatherBlock is null");
            return convertView;
        }

        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView minTempFoDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minTempOfDay);
        TextView maxTempFoDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.maxTempOfDay);
        ListView weatherHolderListView = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wHoldLV);

        String dateString = dayBlock.get(position);
        dayWeather = json.extractByDate(weatherBlock, dateString);

        if (dayWeather == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "getView: dayweather array is null");
            return convertView;
        }

        if (position > dayWeather.getSize() - 1)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "getView: the position is too great for the dayWeather array");
            return convertView;
        }

        String test = dayWeather.get(position).getTemp(); // error occured here
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: test string : " + test);

        date.setText(dateString);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        float mint = 500, maxt = 0;
        String mint1 = "", maxt1 = "";

        for (WeatherData data : dayWeather)
        {
            if (mint > Float.parseFloat(data.getMinTemp()))
            {
                mint = Float.parseFloat(data.getMinTemp());
                mint1 = df.format(mint);
                Log.d(TAG, "getView: mint : " + mint);
            }

            if (maxt > Float.parseFloat(data.getMaxTemp()))
            {
                maxt = Float.parseFloat(data.getMaxTemp());
                maxt1 = df.format(maxt);
            }
        }

        minTempFoDay.setText(mint1);
        maxTempFoDay.setText(maxt1);

        WeatherAdapter weatherAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(context, R.layout.weather_holder, dayWeather);
        weatherHolderListView.setAdapter(weatherAdapter);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll definitely try it

Comment: I discovered that the data I had extracted in a new list made problems so I changed the function that extracted the data, The viewHolder worked and the ui was smoother.